# What SSO solution can be used that doesn't require a prompt from the user, and doesn't rely on fixed redirect URIs?

Tags: django, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm looking for a SSO solution that meets the following requirements:

- User accounts are stored on **Site A** (running on Django)
- **Site A** also provides API
- **Site B** needs to make authenticated & authorized API calls to **Site A**
- Users already logged into **Site A** should not have to enter credentials again

Also, a weird requirement is that we cannot "trust" **Site B** based on its domain name alone (the web app runs containerized on a 3rd-party service, which generates the app's domain randomly -- though we *can* store secrets on the container if needed).

I've looked into OAuth2, however it seems that requires a `redirect_uri` to be configured for the app (**Site B**) on the auth server (**Site A**). Unfortunately the domain for the app is dynamically generated on a per-user basis, so there's no way to know URI to supply ahead of time (unless I build some fancy workaround where the app container "registers" itself with the auth server on startup).

I thought of rolling my own token-based authentication system, however, I didn't want to re-invent the wheel if there was already a standard for doing just that. Is there anything out there that meets these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my options, I decided to use a custom authentication flow similar to [django-simple-sso](https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso). The authentication scheme is non-standard AFAIK, but it handles my use case.

If anyone is curious, the authentication flow goes like this:

1. A "client app" representing **Site B** is created on **Site A**, with a `client_id` and `secret`
2. **Site B** makes a back-end API request for a "request token", along with an Authorization header containing the `client_id` and `client_secret`.
3. This "request token" allows the **Site B** to send a user to `/sso/auth` on **Site A**, along with a `next` parameter. **Site A** will not redirect without a valid request token.
4. The `/sso/auth` page requires user session-based authentication. Once authenticated, the user is redirected to the `next` parameter with `token` added in the query string. The request token is also deleted at this point.
5. This auth token can now be used in the `Authorize` header for API calls.